# Split not caught the symbols

Tags: java, split, subset-sum

I'm trying do [this exercice](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/68oda5/20170501_challenge_313_easy_subset_sum/)

I'm using split to delete the "[", "]" and ",".

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String cadena, cadenaDelimitadores;

    cadena = sc.nextLine();

    cadenaDelimitadores = "[ .,;?!¡¿\'\"\\[\\]]+";

    String[] cadenaString = cadena.split(cadenaDelimitadores);

    int[] cadenaInt = new int[cadenaString.length];

    try{

        for (int i = 0; i < cadenaString.length; i++) {

            cadenaInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(cadenaString[i]);

            System.out.println(cadenaInt[i]);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){

        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
```

When I execute the code there are some symbols from split that not caught.

Input example:

```
[-3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: what is the input? and what you expect like output?

Comment: The input:
[-3, 1, 2], I save the numbers in string and i parse this string to Int.

Comment: You could start by replacing `[` and `]` with nothing, and then call `split(",")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **split** and check many cases, you are use **Pattern** instead here is an example :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[-3, 1, 2]");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Outputs**

```
-3
1
2
```